# Auto Increment scala, hibernate with postgress database

Tags: hibernate, scala, postgresql-9.1

I am using scala, hibernate with postgress database

how to auto increment the id which is primary key and serial in postgress data base

here is my model

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "event_user")
class User( id: Option[Long] = None, email1: String, password: String, first_name1: String, last_name1: String) {

  @Id
  var id: Long = _

  @Column(name = "email")
  var email : String = email1

  @Column(name = "password")
  var passWord : String = password

  @Column(name = "first_name")
  var first_name : String = first_name1

  @Column(name = "last_name")
  var last_name : String = last_name1

  def this() = this (None, null, null, null, null)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell JPA that `id` should be autogenerated by using `@GeneratedValue` annotation. You can find an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11825643/configure-jpa-to-let-postgresql-generate-the-primary-key-value)