# How force Hibernate create table with type Serial for primary Key

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql

In my spring project, the field Id (used as primary key for my entity classes), have this annotations:

```
@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;
```

But when the Hibernate create the table in my postgresql database, this field is created with the type Integer. I would like this field to be created with type Serial. Is there any way to do that?

**UPDATE**

I change the declaration for the field If for this:

```
@Id
@Column(name = "id", columnDefinition = "serial")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
```

and now, nothing is created in the database when I start the application with a blank database.

**UPDATE 2**

I tested with this configuration:

```
@SequenceGenerator(allocationSize=1, initialValue=1, sequenceName="usuario_id_seq", name="usuario_id_seq")
@GeneratedValue(generator="usuario_id_seq", strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@Generated(GenerationTime.INSERT)
@Id
@Column(name="id", columnDefinition="serial")
private Integer id;
```

the tables are created, but the primary key is created as `integer`, and not `serial`, what I want.

Comment: what about `strategy=GenerationType.identity`?

Comment: no, still creating the primary key as integer.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183932/hibernate-annotation-for-postgresql-serial-type) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979746/mapping-postgresql-serial-type-with-hibernate-annotations). You can check [this](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=994105) as well

Comment: Ok, then I read the links and follow the sugestions, but now nothing is created in the database (I am starting with a blank database - see update in the question).